# How to resolve communication between my WPF application and a hosted IExplorer?

Tags: wpf, architecture

For a rather large project i have to figure out how (if possible) to resolve this problem. I have a full screen WPF application doing a slideshow - following an interval of e.g. 20 secs per slide. Now I have to investigate into the possibility of replacing the slideshow with a URL instead and have the user navigate the slides instead of changing slides every 10 seconds. The setup is like this:

1. First the timed slideshow will run, e.g. 5 slides
2. I show my web page and lets the user interact with the website (navigating)
3. When the user **"Does something (this is the problem)"** the website is removed from "slide" and the original slideshow is resumed

The container being shown is a WPF UserControl with an event that allows it to change to the next slide (call a Next() method). The IExporer is hosted within this control.

The problem im facing is this: how do i communicate from the website that my hosting application has to call the NExt() method?

The IExplorer showing the website is hosted within my WPF UserControl. Is there any way i can access some kind of event or anything else to help me determine if a particular page or a particular link has been pressed??

WebServices, files on disc, you name it, im ready to try anything :-)

Any advice or possible solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the WebBrowser control in your WPF application, you can call into C# classes using javascript from your html.  For example, let's say you have a class similar to the following:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class JavaScriptBackEnd
{
    public void onclick(string s)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

Then initialize the WebBrowser control with the following code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new JavaScriptBackEnd();
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(@"HTMLPage1.htm"));
}
```

From HTMLPage1.htm you can now call the JavaScriptBackEnd.onclick method with the following javascript:

```
function testclick() {
    window.external.onclick('blabla');
}
```